# Spark Setup on Mac, running into SSH authentication error with sbin/start-all.sh

Tags: macos, authentication, apache-spark, ssh, localhost

New to spark: trying to run it for the first time locally just to test some functionality. The shell works fine, and almost everything works with basic configurations around localhost.

Here's the problem: 
When running ./start-all.sh (Which sets some basic params and runs start-master.sh and a few other files) I hit a prompt for password and behavior gets funky here. 
When entering no password, or one that is definitely not my local admin password, I receive the prompt again, for 3 times total followed by the last one shown below (which I assume is just for clarification).

```
Password:
Password:
Password:
squid@localhost's password:
```

However, this does not persist if I enter my local admin password, and returns the following message, assuming I've typed my password into the prompt shown:

```
Password: 
localhost: Authentication failed.
```

I've narrowed down the issue to slaves.sh which calls an ssh with the following command :

```
if [ "$SPARK_SSH_OPTS" = "" ]; then
  SPARK_SSH_OPTS="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
fi

for slave in `echo "$HOSTLIST"|sed  "s/#.*$//;/^$/d"`; do
  if [ -n "${SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND}" ]; then
    ssh $SPARK_SSH_OPTS "$slave" $"${@// /\\ }" \
      2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /"
  else
    ssh $SPARK_SSH_OPTS "$slave" $"${@// /\\ }" \
      2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /" &
  fi
```

Which makes me wonder if there would be any local issues with running ssh. However, after testing ssh functionality, it works for other services and I'm never prompted for my local password.

Comment: Did you ever try `ssh localhost`?

Answer (score 1):

Narrowed down the fix to Remote Login in System Preferences.

To fix: Open System Preferences -> Sharing -> Check Remote Login if unchecked. If your username is not listed, add yourself to the list. SSH will not allow you to "remotely" connect to your own server for some reason.
(To add yourself, click the lock on the bottom right of the pane to unlock and make changes, then click the "+" to add your user to the list.)